# Edit LabVIEW palette sets automatically

Tags: installation, labview, palette

I have a device driver I am installing to the user.lib folder, there are various .mnu files included in the driver. After I install my driver I need to go to

Tools->Advanced->Edit Palette Sets...

And create a new sub palette from the mnu file.

Is it possible to automate this? I would rather the user could simply install the driver and their palettes would already be taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

There is an application method App.Palettes.Refresh that refreshes the current palette set.
You can create a VI that is being executed during your installation:
[image: App.Palette.Refresh]

Of course your mnu files should be under vi.lib, instr.lib or user.lib

Answer (score 1):

If you use [VIPM](http://jki.net) (VI Package Manager), you can use their interface to lay out the functions pallet. Then installing the Package will place the VIs accordingly.

VIPM ships standard with LV2012, so most people are going to start to use it to distribute their plugins in the LabVIEW marketplace.